# Is MySQL `IF` statement atomic?

Tags: mysql, atomic

Assuming the multiple applications use this statement to assure exclusivity with [MySQL Locking Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/locking-functions.html)

```sql
SELECT IF(IS_USED_LOCK(:name) = CONNECTION_ID(), -1, GET_LOCK(:name, 0))
```

I'm wondering whether the `IF` statement is atomic (can it happen that lock gets acquired multiple times)

Comment: If you're using auto-commit, every query is a transaction, so it's atomic. If not, you have a transaction between `BEGIN TRANSACTION;` and `COMMIT;`